# How to access dynamic text field on stage from within the document class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to access a text input that I've already placed on the stage (inside a movie clip) but with no luck.

I've defined an instance name for this dynamic text field which is currentUserCount

I've got something like this set up in the document class actionscript file:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class myProject extends Sprite {

        public function myProject() {
            // Trying stuff like
            trace(currentUserCount);
            trace(movieClipName.currentUserCount);
            trace(root.currentUserCount);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

When I run this I get:

```
1120: Access of undefined property currentUserCount.
1120: Access of undefined property movieClipName.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property movieClipName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
1120: Access of undefined property currentUserCount.
```

Comment: Are you getting any compiler errors? What happens when you trace movieClipName?

Comment: I've added the compiler output

Comment: It's hard to get a good idea without seeing the .fla, but my guess would be the movieclip doesn't have an instance name.

Comment: The movie clip is nested inside another movie clip, does that matter?

Comment: ahh.. ok, it does matter. So now I'm referencing animation1.movieClipName and I can set/retrieve the textbox's text, but as soon as the movie clip loops again, the text in the textbox gets reset.

Also, this textbox is referenced in other movie clips, so I would like it somehow always to be set to the new value.

Can I somehow add the code to a create event or something on the movie clip I have around the textbox?

Comment: Yes it does :) You need to provide a full path to the text field, and each item must have an instance name. When the compiler says "Access of undefined property movieClipName" it means "Hey, I can't find a movieclip with this name." It's up to you to name items so that your code may access them.

Comment: you should stop on first frame, by `stop()` command, to stop updating and loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the movieclips on the stage had the same nested clip inside of it, you could also just reference the inner clips like so:

```
for (var i=0; i<stage.numChildren; i++){
  var mc = stage.getChildAt(i)
  mc.subClip.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MovieClip and the TextField have instance names in your .fla file.

```
// MovieClip instance name: mc;
// Textfield instance name: tf;
```

Then in your document class:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class myProject extends Sprite {

        public function myProject() {
            mc.tf.text = "Text you wanna see";
            trace(mc.tf); // [Object TextField]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was referencing a movie clip within a movie clip and I didn't know I had to create an instance name for each one and work my way in code through each one.

I thought the instance names were a part of a global namespace.

So I was doing something like:

```
myMovieClip.play();
```

when I should have been doing:

```
mainMovieClip.subMovieClip.myMovieClip.play();
```