# New to ActionScript3, Making calculator and stuck

Tags: actionscript-3, calculator

first time here on stackoverflow and first time scripting in flashCS6.
ill get down to it - the only lang ive done is html and a bit of css. I tried learning java, but gave up since i realised im making flash games so might as well just do AS3. Its pretty similar and not at all at the  same time.
As my first original program (i did a tutorial of pong from a website before, got to know a bit about functions and event handlers`[http://as3gametuts.com/2011/03/19/pong-1/]`), im trying to create a calculator, and  what  want to know is how i can return the values from two input fields, put them into a logic calculator (say input a is 1 and input b is 2, and there are four functions, each attached to an event listener for the 4 mathematical operations, and i press addition so the calculator goes 2+1=3) 
main question here, how do i get the outut text field to display the answer. In java i just used `system.out.println(inputA + inputB).`
Here i tried to do out.text = ( a + b) (where out is output , a is input and b is input 2)

Here is the code i have so far:
a is input 1, b is input 2
Out is output
and mul, add, sub and div are symbols containing dynamic test fields with instance names adn, sub, mul and div respectively. The symbol instances are the same as the test instances) Ex: i have a text field that says addition, its instance name is adn, then i convert it to a symbol and make its instance name adn as well.

```
a.text.restrict = "0-9";
b.text.restrict = "0-9";

mul.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, output);
adn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addition);
sub.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subtraction);
div.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, division);
a.addEventListener(TextInput,input);
b.addEventListener(TextInput,input);

function output ():void
{
    out.text=("test to see if output works")
}
function input (e:TextInput)
{

}
function multiplication (e:MouseEvent)
{

}

function addition (e:MouseEvent)
{

}
function subtraction (e:MouseEvent)
{

}
function division (e:MouseEvent)
{

}
```

thanks guys, and cheers! Also, ill appreciate if anyone can link me to a good video or text tutorial (series) for AS3 introduction. My main focus is to be making PC games and not apps, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630181/how-to-access-dynamic-text-field-on-stage-from-within-the-document-class) Out

Also, don't forget to convert value to string, that may be neccessary:

```
out.text = String(a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a text field will give you the input typecast as a string you will need to type cast them to type Number or type int before you can do any kind of math function on them.
And if you want to create a more complex calculator I would suggest you read up on the [Math class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html)

```
function subtraction (e:MouseEvent)
{
  var result:Number = Number(a.text) - Number(b.text)
  out.text = String(result)
}
```